# Team Fortress 2 using more CPU on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS than in Windows 8

Tags: laptop, steam, cpu

CPU: AMD A6-4400M APU with Radeon HD Graphics (Radeon HD 7520G)  RAM: 8 GB (I use Ubuntu 64-bit) Driver using: X.org X server (not a proprietary driver)  Also, I don't use wine for Team Fortress 2 (Steam game). I get great frames per second but I get very high CPU usage. I have played TF2 on Windows 8 using the same laptop and it uses about 40% to 75% CPU, Ubuntu probably uses 80% to 95% constantly.  Can you please help me with this? Let me know if you need more information Thank you  :)

Comment: Do you get the same framerate on Windows as in Linux?

Comment: The framerate is about the same. Difference is the CPU usage between Windows 8 and Ubuntu. I'm not really going to worry about this issue much because I am going to build my own computer with better hardware.

Comment: Look into a better GPU driver

Comment: I tried to use the non-opensource drivers before and I can't play the game unless I switch it back to opensource drivers. Sadly, I am going to use Windows for the computer I am going to build so I don't have to deal with these problems.

Comment: You may want to try downloading the official SteamOS flavor of Linux and se how things work ther.e